# Changeing directory in R studio when installing packages

Tags: r

How do i choose the library which the package is install in in Rstudio?

When i run "install and restart" i get this error:

```
installing to library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library'
Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library'
Exited with status 1.
```

I want it to install on "h:/r_packages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to install your personal package. I don't find any option for the library path in RStudio. You can run this code in the console:

```
withr::with_libpaths("h:/r_packages", devtools::install())
```

You have to run this command when the current directory is the one of the package. Otherwise use the `pkg` argument of `devtools::install` to specify the package directory.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `install.packages` is `lib`, which specifies the library directory.
The help reads:

```
lib 

character vector giving the library directories
where to install the packages.
Recycled as needed.
If missing, defaults to the first element of .libPaths().
```

So, the below would work, though I cannot try on my end.

```r
install.packages("package_name", lib="h:/r_packages")
```

Comment: That is correct when its a package from CRAN.. this is a package i have build my self.